# python argparse : how to override all other parameters - like --help does in most programs?

Tags: python, argparse

We have a bunch of scripts that use a standard set of parameters. These are defined in a class that all scripts use. Each scripts can add additional parameters as needed.

I'm trying to add a new parameter that should act like --help in that if present, all other parameters are ignored. When the new parameter (--doc_string) is given, I want all other parameters to be ignored, I will print a specific string and exit. Is there a way to do this with `argparse`?

I've looked at using groups like this:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
group1 = parser.add_argument_group('docs', 'doc printing')
group1.add_argument('--doc_string', action = 'store_true', help='print the doc string and exit')
group2 = parser.add_argument_group('group2', 'group2 description')
group2.add_argument('--bar', required=True, help='bar help')
group2.add_argument('--blah',required=True, help='url used to test.')
parser.parse_args()
```

But when run with just --doc_string, I still get the message `--bar is required`. Exclusive groups isn't right either.

I've also looked at subclassing `argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter` or `argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter` or `argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter` but can't get a handle on how to use those to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Comment: have you tried parsing args after defining your group1 arguments? Then if there is no --doc-string, add your other arguments, and parse the arguments again ?

Comment: interesting approach. Just tried it. If `argparse` only knows about `--doc_string` but sees other parameters like `--bar`, it complains about parameters: `error: unrecognized arguments: --bar --blah`. I would need a way to peek at the list of arguments before argparse validates them.

Comment: Do you know about this : `sys.argv` ? 
https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sys.html#sys.argv

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Register your own action with the parser.  Then you can do it the same way `--help`, `--version` etc do it, i.e. by specifying the action.

```
import argparse

class DocstringAction(argparse.Action):

    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        print('see ya later alligator')
        parser.exit()

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
parser.register('action', 'docstring', DocstringAction)
group1 = parser.add_argument_group('docs', 'doc printing')
group1.add_argument('--doc_string', nargs=0, action='docstring', help='print the doc string and exit')
group2 = parser.add_argument_group('group2', 'group2 description')
group2.add_argument('--bar', required=True, help='bar help')
group2.add_argument('--blah',required=True, help='url used to test.')
parser.parse_args()
```

If you don't need any arguments for the docstring action, then you could (should) push the `nargs=0` into `DocstringAction.__init__` so that it's not necessary to specify that.

Comment: Right, the key to the `help` override is that 'parser.exit()`.  The 'version` action class also does this.

Comment: The only concern I have about this solution is that usage of `parser.register` undocumented. I had dug around before posting and was surprised I hadn't uncovered this approach. I suppose that means it could disappear in a future release but for now it's functions perfectly.

Comment: It is not necessary to register the action if you don't want to.  This usage is documented: you can pass a custom action class directly, `action=DocstringAction` instead of `action='docstring'`.